# Ошибка при установке WSL

Tags: wsl

Всем привет, при установке wsl такая ошибка, надеюсь на помощь[image: нажмите для просмотра ошибки]

Я пробовал устанавливать wsl по гайдам от разных сайтов, к примеру microsoft. Пересмотрел куча видео. Но все привело ни к чему.

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)